# Raster to Ascii by python console in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, esri-ascii-raster, qgis-python-console

I'm working on PyQgis.

I have to convert a **raster** file to a file **.asc**. The classic procedure through the Qgis Menu is:

Raster -> Translate (convert format) -> on "Ouput file" select Arc / Info ASCII Grid.

Can this procedure be queried by the python console? What is the command?

**EDIT**

I tried to run:

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:translate', '/path/to/raster.tif',100.0,True,None,0,'',None,False,5,4,75.0,6.0,1.0,False,0,False,None,'/path/to/output.asc')
```

But the result was:

```
Error: Wrong parameter value: None
```

Why?

Comment: You can use GDAL_Translate -of AAIGRID from a command window. The raster translate menu is only a shortcut to GDAL_Translate. http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html If you only have QGIS installed and not GDAL the paths may not be set correctly, open your command window in the folder that contains the file gdal_translate.exe and it should work; there's no external driver needed for this format so paths shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @MichaelStimson sorry but your answer does not help me. I edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: It looks like your rtype needs to be specified (last parameter before output file) https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/translate.html (default 5 = Float32).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably due to the `PROJWIN <ParameterExtent>` parameter where you need to specify the extent of the raster layer.

Try running the following:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import processing

raster = 'path/to/raster'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster, baseName)
extent = rlayer.extent()
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = extent.xMinimum(), extent.xMaximum(), extent.yMinimum(), extent.yMaximum()
processing.runalg('gdalogr:translate',rlayer,100.0,True,None,0,'',"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),False,5,4,75.0,6.0,1.0,False,0,False,None,'/path/to/output.asc')
```

Comment: I've already tried this solution and created the file **.asc** but when I load it on Qgis I get a visual result that is identical, but the maximum and minimum values (in the layer panel legend) are wrong. It is as if the 2 values reported in the legend represent the total number of NODATA and the total number of valid data and not the real value.

Comment: @DomenicoFuoco - Right-click your .asc file and to go `Properties > Style`. In the _Load min/max values_ section, choose the `Min / max` and set the _Accuracy_ to `Actual (slower)`. Then click _Load_. This should give you the correct result :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I had made a mistake in returning your procedure. It works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @DomenicoFuoco - No problem! Glad you got it working :)